# replace .click() with ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs-ng-click

I'm sure this is just because I'm using it wrong, but I'm very confused. This all started when I was convinced to move my Angular site that I'm building over to using a router.  As a result, a lot of my jQuery code stopped working.

For example I have a navigation line under a slideshow with endcap arrows and dots for each slide. When you click an arrow, it advances or moves back on. You can click on a dot as well and get that slide. This was my code:

```
  $('#arrow-next').click(function() {

    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
      nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }

    currentSlide.removeClass('active-slide').fadeOut(600, function(){
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
    });

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');

  });
  // END Clicking NEXT arrow

    $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {

    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
      prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
      prevDot = $('.dot').last();
    }

    currentSlide.removeClass('active-slide').fadeOut(600, function(){
        prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
    });

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');

    }); // end click

    $('.dot').click(function() {

        var index = $('.dot').index($(this));

        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var newSlide = $('.slide').eq(index);

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var newDot = $(this);

        currentSlide.removeClass('active-slide').fadeOut(600, function(){
            newSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
        });

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        newDot.addClass('active-dot');

    }); // end click
```

I want to turn these into functions that I can call on ng-clck but I can't figure out how.

Comment: UPDATE: I actually finally got the arrows working. I can't figure out the dots yet though. I'm having trouble capturing the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you are using the class dot, add ng-click to that html tag. That should solve the problem.
Convert the click function to a scope function and send it as parameters to ng-click.
But it is advisable not to have DOM manipulations in your controller. You will have problems incase you have to write unit test cases for the same later. All the DOM manipulation should be carried out in your directive.